# How to call return from a constructor without marking properties as undefined?

Tags: typescript

I use a file of exported constant as preprocessor directives. Now I would like to completely strip the body of a constructor if this directive is set. For example:

```js
const MY_PREPROCESSOR_DIRECTIVE = true;

class Foo {
    someProp: string;
    constructor() {
        if (MY_PREPROCESSOR_DIRECTIVE) return;

        this.someProp = "string";
    }
}
```

This works nicely, I'm using closure compiler for building, which strips the body and the whole thing is turned into only just:

```
class Foo {}
```

In TypeScript this causes errors though, because `someProp` and `otherProp` are "not definitely assigned in the constructor". And in JavaScript files, I don't get errors in the constructor, but all properties are getting set to `string | undefined`:

```js
const MY_PREPROCESSOR_DIRECTIVE = false;

class Foo {
    constructor() {
        if (MY_PREPROCESSOR_DIRECTIVE) return;

        this.someProp = "string";
    }

    myMethod() {
        if (MY_PREPROCESSOR_DIRECTIVE) return;

        this.someProp.substring(0);
//      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^------ Object is possibly 'undefined'.
    }
}
```

([js playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictNullChecks=true&downlevelIteration=true&preserveConstEnums=true&inlineSources=false&preserveValueImports=false&filetype=js#code/MYewdgzgLgBAsgTQPoAUBKBRdB5AwhgZQOzSQBEBJTXAFQoDUMYBeGAMwEMAbCAUwG4AUIOBcOECDABiIEDADegmMpihIUAE4BXYFBAaAFAEoFSleYCWbGAcSpMOfERLkqGWgwwmNvKFo1gQmbmylAAFhYQAHQQIAC2vCgaIAAOLDAARNAaFmAA5hlC5gC+wuZxAJ5wvmEgACbGpiEqVjZ26FhoeITEpJTUdIzevv6BwSHj5uGRMfGJySkxWgBG2bl5BgAMRkIA9LvNAHrHJ6cnALSXVzDYywBWvLowkTApIBIWy1wVMADkWmA6rw2LleHVflFxqVikA) | [ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?downlevelIteration=true&preserveConstEnums=true&inlineSources=false&preserveValueImports=false&filetype=ts#code/MYewdgzgLgBAsgTQPoAUBKBRdB5AwhgZQOzSQBEBJTXAFQoDUMYBeGAMwEMAbCAUwG4AUIOBcOECDABiIEDADegmMpgQQAW14oATiAAOALlVRtASzABzIQHprygHqOnjgLRv3LmDv29tUAJ4wAORqmt56QTAAFuIwYHLmplCm3KYAXr4wHGAAJoK2KoVFxaaS8bA5vGyJULxcgeIQphZgvDkw5jBQUbwwoJAmAK7AUCDaAHRKKv3Q2sOj2gAUAJQKUyVsMIuIqJg4+EQk5FQYtAwYq9q8UIPaYELrRd2l46FaunosMABEs+YW3yEhQAvsJCup-HBrlEQDkVmtispTJttsh0Fg0HhCMRSJRqHRGJdrrd7o9Cs8IK8NO99K9BgAjP6WRYABmWQJUoOBQA))

Is there a way to let TypeScript know the directive will always be false so that it doesn't mark `this.someProp` as `string | undefined`? I tried to mark the `return` statement of the constructor as unreachable code, but I'm not sure how to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since TS know nothing `bout runtime` MY_PREPROCESSOR_DIRECTIVE` I think it worth using strategy pattern.

SO, you have two variants of `Foo` class. One with `MY_PREPROCESSOR_DIRECTIVE = true` and another one with `MY_PREPROCESSOR_DIRECTIVE = false`.

```js
const MY_PREPROCESSOR_DIRECTIVE = false;

interface Foo {
    someProp?: string;
    myMethod: () => void
}

class WithDirective implements Foo {
    someProp: string;

    constructor() {
        this.someProp = "string";
    }
    myMethod() {
        this.someProp.substring(0)
    }
}

class WithoutDirective implements Foo {
    someProp: undefined
    constructor() { }
    myMethod() { }
}

const Foo = MY_PREPROCESSOR_DIRECTIVE ? WithDirective : WithoutDirective
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/m0oADN)

If you don't like the fact that there will be always 1 unused class in a build, you can use class expression:

```js
const MY_PREPROCESSOR_DIRECTIVE = false;

interface Foo {
    someProp?: string;
    myMethod: () => void
}

const Foo =
    MY_PREPROCESSOR_DIRECTIVE
        ? class implements Foo {
            someProp: string;

            constructor() {
                this.someProp = "string";
            }
            myMethod() {
                this.someProp.substring(0)
            }
        }
        : class implements Foo {
            someProp: undefined
            constructor() { }
            myMethod() { }
        }
```

Personally, I think first example is more readable and easier to maintain. Also, I don't think that it will have a significant impact on your bundle size.

Comment: Thanks! This seems like a good solution, I'll try this later today. Regarding the bundle size, the whole point of the directive was to reduce the bundle size xD. Though I believe closure compiler will remove the unused class even in the first example.

Comment: @Jespertheend Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with closure compiler and I don't know if unused class in first scenario will be removed.  SO maybe second scenario will be better for your use case

Comment: The first approach seems to work with my specific build pipeline. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems one way to work around this issue, in JavaScript anyway, is to explicitly set the type using JSDoc:

```js
constructor() {
    if (MY_PREPROCESSOR_DIRECTIVE) return;

    /** @type {string} */
    this.someProp = "string";
}
```

([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictNullChecks=true&downlevelIteration=true&preserveConstEnums=true&inlineSources=false&preserveValueImports=false&ssl=9&ssc=6&pln=4&pc=1&filetype=js#code/MYewdgzgLgBAsgTQPoAUBKBRdB5AwhgZQOzSQBEBJTXAFQoDUMYBeGAMwEMAbCAUwG4AUIOBcOECDABiIEDADegmMpihIUAE4BXYFBAaAFAEoFSleYCWbGAcSpMOfERLkqGWgwwmNvKFo1gQmbmygD0AFThMAACUACeAA68CtAaFmAA5gC%20MOGhwSFQABYWEAB0ECAAtrwoGiAJLDAARKnpGc1C5lnC5lVxcL5FIAAmxqYhKlY2duhYaHiExKSU1HSM3r7%20gQXmuyrFpRXVtfUJFVoARm2ZBgAMRkKhoZMAeu8fnx8AtL9-MLwNPUNDBSjAMuBkoAeDcAkfsFHpZIA))

I'm not sure if there's a similar way to do this with TypeScript, so this might very well be unintentional behaviour.